# Magento: Adding more than one 'Tag' to a collection filter

Tags: php, sql, magento

It was a long weekend and my brain isn't working, I am trying to filter a product collection by more than one tag. On a 'tag/product_collection' I can only supply one value to 'addTagFilter' so I am trying to pass my own statement in to where()

```
relation.tag_id = 6 AND relation.tag_id = 9
```

but its returning none, even though there are 6 products that have both tags 6 AND 9, I can change the query to IN (6,9) and it returns all products that have either and removing the AND and selecting say just 6 or 9 works fine but for the life of me I cant work out why AND isn't returning?! Full code below.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('tag/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','simple');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->getSelect()->where("relation.tag_id = 6 AND relation.tag_id = 9","");
```

Thanks in advance.

=== EDIT ===
Okay, well I didn't have much luck trying to workout the 'SQL' way of doing this on the collection, so if anyone finds one feel free to list it below and we'll all upvote the shiz out of it. In the meantime, I have a slightly bodged way of doing it. I would not recommend this if you have 1000's of products, I can imagine it being a little slow.

```
// Load our collection
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('tag/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','simple');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
->addAttributeToSelect('name');

// Loop the collection  
foreach ( $collection as $_product)
    {   
    // Load ALL tags for product
    $model = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
    $tags = $model->getResourceCollection()
        ->addPopularity()
        ->addStatusFilter($model->getApprovedStatus())
        ->addProductFilter($_product->getId())
        ->setFlag('relation', true)
        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->setActiveFilter()
        ->load();

    // loop through all the tags if we find one set a flag to skip returning this product.
    $arr = array();
    foreach($tags as $_t){ $arr[$_t->getId()] = $_t->getName(); }

    $filter_tags = count($_REQUEST['tags']) > 0 ? $_REQUEST['tags'] : array();
    $tag_found = 0;
    $on_filter =  count($filter_tags) > 0 ? 1 : 0;

    foreach($arr as $key => $value){ array_key_exists($key,$filter_tags) ? $tag_found++ : 0; }

    // if all if good send the product to an array to be returned
    if($on_filter && $tag_found){ // add $_product to a return }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this code

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('tag/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','simple');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->getSelect()->Where('relation.tag_id=?', 6)
        ->Where('relation.tag_id=?', 9);
```

You can put multiple where class and by default it's add the `"AND"` and if you want `"OR"` then you can use `orWhere` instead of `Where`

Comment: Thanks Amit, this way essentially does the same thing as my above code, I can see in the SELECT both add the AND SQL jus fine but it still wont select the right results maybe it has something do do with way its collecting the related tags?! :s

Comment: So when you are using individual relation_tag_id condition then its returning some results if yes the checkout the product ids, May be no products having tag_id 6 and 9.